# I'm using http.server with python3 and I want to store a request as a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, simplehttpserver, http.server, simplehttprequesthandler

I have this code

```
httpd = HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 8000),SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.handle_request()
```

httpd.handle_request() serves one request and then kills the server like intended. I want to capture this request as a variable so I can parse it later on.
Something like

```
Request_Variable = httpd.handle_request()
```

*This code above doesn't work. But I'm looking for something similar
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` and implement your own `do_GET` (resp. `do_POST`) method which is called when the server receives a GET (resp. POST) request.

Check out the documentation to see what instance variables a `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` object you can use. The variables `path`, `headers`, `rfile` and `wfile` may be of your interest.

```py
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

class MyRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  def do_GET(self):
    print(self.path)
  def do_POST(self):
    content_length = int(self.headers.get('Content-Length'))
    print(self.rfile.read(content_length))

httpd = HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 8000), MyRequestHandler)
httpd.handle_request()
# make your GET/POST request
```

Comment: Thank you so much. 
I ended up adding a few lines in this and now it works just fine.
```class MyRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    request = ""
    def do_GET(self):
        # print(self.path)
        MyRequestHandler.request = self.path
    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers.get('Content-Length'))
        print(self.rfile.read(content_length))

httpd = HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 8000), MyRequestHandler)
httpd.handle_request()
print("\n\n", MyRequestHandler.request)```